# Using rqt with rviz

Tags: ros-fuerte, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to use rviz in rqt, I'm using fuerte and Ubuntu 10.04.
When I do:

```
rosrun rqt_rviz rqt_rviz
```

I get:

```
    /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rqt/rqt_gui/src/rqt_gui/roslib_plugin_provider.py:31: UserWarning: roslib.rospack is deprecated, please use rospkg
  import roslib.rospack
RosPluginlibPluginProvider::load_explicit_type(rqt_rviz/RViz) failed initializing plugin (plugin is not a nodelet)
PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_rviz/RViz":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/qt_gui_core/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 89, in load
    self._load()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/qt_gui_core/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 54, in _load
    self._plugin = self._plugin_provider.load(self._instance_id.plugin_id, self._context)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/qt_gui_core/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/qt_gui_core/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/qt_gui_core/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load
    instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/qt_gui_core/qt_gui_cpp/src/qt_gui_cpp/ros_pluginlib_plugin_provider.py", line 68, in load
    raise ImportError('RosPluginlibPluginProvider.load() could not load plugin "%s"' % plugin_id)
ImportError: RosPluginlibPluginProvider.load() could not load plugin "rqt_rviz/RViz"
```

Also, if I open directly rqt with

```
rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui
```

and then I try to add manually Rviz plugin, I get the same error.

What could I do to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58021/using-rqt-with-rviz/) by [BLaS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1491/blas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-03-14**:
Wouldn't blame fuerte generally, works for me in up to date fuerte under 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I confirm that this happens on my environment too (see below for the versions). I would say if it's possible for you then you should better use ROS Groovy, since `rqt` is still kind of experimental in `fuerte`.

fuerte Ubuntu 10.04 64b. ros-fuerte-qt-gui-core 0.1.4-s1359894656~lucid

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the same error in fuerte.
But with roscore runnning , rqt starts successfully.

You may try to run roscore before rqt.

---

Originally posted by [Yuichi Komori](https://answers.ros.org/users/4521/yuichi-komori/) with karma: 11 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1